# C++ unresolved external symbol D3DX11

Tags: c++, external, symbols

Hey I get the following error at compiling the source:

```
unresolved external symbol "D3DX11CreateTextureFromMemory".
```

If i rightclick the method I am able to jump to the declaration which is found in "D3DX11tex.h"

I added "include <d3dx11.h>" to my source but it still gives me that error.
What can I do about that?

Comment: d3dx is deprecated.

Comment: im using an imugi directx11 source which should work with it

Comment: Are you linking with `D3DX11.lib` see __Requirements__ here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3dx11createtexturefrommemory